# How to read raw folder file name which has space between words

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a few mp3 files in raw folder in which some of the file name have two words.I mean space between the words.Please help me how to read the file name.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Android does not allow resources with spaces in names. So I would suggest to replace spaces in file names with "_" and use those.

context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sf_sd)

Comment: Thanks for the help.I used underscore between the words but it doesn't look good in text view.I thought is there some way to avoid underscore.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid resource naming. Replace all spaces with underline character (`_`):

> Original - original file name.mp3
>
> Changed  - original_file_name.mp3

This will allow you to access that file through [Resources.openRawResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)) API.